# Chrome devtools authored scripts and deployed scripts which one takes effect after an edit

Tags: java, html, jquery, css

> I'm trying to edit a javascript source file on a Web page and for some reason, it didn't run as expected as I'm not even sure it took effect at all.
> Though there was a division in the code that goes like "i37376363636hsbs.js" which is just a very long single-lined .js file that I don't understand but on careful reading seems to be a separate version of the original that looks ugly and is grouped as the deployed code.
> And then there's the "main.js" that looks perfectly written.
> And that's the one I edited but it grouped as the authored code.
> So I just want to know if the authored code is not gonna refresh in real-time, as that's the code I understand and can read.
> And what's the difference between both of them in code editing performance?
> Please do note that I'm not planning on debugging any code just edit the high-level stuff and forget about it.
> Thanks

I tried to modify the high-level authored code but I wasn't sure if it's gonna take effect without the deployed code?.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.